# Controlling Node Values with python custom UI / FloatPropetie

Tags: python, materials, node-editor, add-on, properties

I am currently trying to make an addon for my Minecraft Pufferfish rig with many options and settings.

Now I am at the point that I have created around 60% of my UI with different properties like int and Float properties.

Now to my question:

How do I use this FloatPropety for controlling a nodes inputs value (in the material; custom node group)

I already found out that you can draw a button of that value but that won't help me because you can't limit it (min, max) and you can't paste it in like box layouts. Or can you?

So is there a way to link that normal float property to a nodes group input?

I'd like to control different node value inputs with these four sliders

Thank you for your help :D

My current code:

```
import bpy

from bpy.props import (StringProperty,
                        BoolProperty,
                        IntProperty,
                        FloatProperty,
                        FloatVectorProperty,
                        EnumProperty,
                        PointerProperty,
                        )


    ### Bl_info ###
    
bl_info = {
    "name": "Pufferfish RIG Addon",
    "author": "BlueEvilGFX",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 83, 0),
    "location": "3DView",
    "description": "Pufferfish RIG Addon for many different Settings",
    "warning": "",
    "support": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "tracker_url": "",
    "category": "Pufferfish"
}  
    

    
                                
                        
    ### Properties ###    

bpy.types.Object.roughness = bpy.props.FloatProperty(
    name = "roughness",
        default = 1,
    min = 0.2,
    max = 5
    )
    
bpy.types.Object.hue = bpy.props.FloatProperty(
    name = "hue",
    default = 0.5,
    min = 0,
    max = 1
    )
    
bpy.types.Object.sss = bpy.props.FloatProperty(
    name = "sss",
    default = 1,
    min = 0,
    max = 1,
    description = "activates SubsurfaceScattering"
    )
    
bpy.types.Object.saturation = bpy.props.FloatProperty(
    name = "saturation",
    default = 1,
    min = 0,
    max = 2,
    )
    
bpy.types.Object.subdivision = bpy.props.IntProperty(
    name = "subdivision",
    default = 0,
    min = 0,
    max = 6,
    )
    
bpy.types.Object.eye_texture_bool = bpy.props.BoolProperty(
    name = "eye_texture",
    default = False,
    )
    
bpy.types.Object.main_material_bool = bpy.props.BoolProperty(
    name = "main_material",
    default = False,
    )
    
bpy.types.Object.eye_texture_type = bpy.props.IntProperty(
    name = "eye_texture_type",
    default = 1,
    min = 1,
    max = 17,
    )
    
bpy.types.Object.eye_color = FloatVectorProperty(  
   name="eye_color",
   subtype='COLOR',
   default=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0),
   min=0.0, max=1.0,
   description="color picker"
   )



    ### Main Panel ###
    
class RIG_UI(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Pufferfish RIG Addon"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_Pufferfish_RIG"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Pufferfish"
    
    @classmethod
    def poll(self, context):
        return bpy.context.object.name == "Pufferfish"
    
    
    def draw(self, context):
    
        
        layout = self.layout
        
        obj = context.object

        
        layout.label(text=" Pufferfish RIG Settings:", icon = "PROPERTIES")
        
        box = layout.box()
        box.label(text = "made by BlueEvilGFX", icon = 'RIGHTARROW')
        

     
class MainSettings(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_parent_id = "OBJECT_PT_Pufferfish_RIG"
    bl_label = "Main Settings"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_MainSettings"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category= "Pufferfish"
    bl_options = {"DEFAULT_CLOSED"}
    
    

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
     
        obj = context.object
         
        
        row = layout.row(align = True)
        row.label(text = "change Main Settings here", icon = 'PREFERENCES')
        
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(obj, "scale")
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(obj, "location")
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(obj, "rotation_euler", text = "Rotation")  




     
     
class Material(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_parent_id = "OBJECT_PT_Pufferfish_RIG"
    bl_label = "Material Settings"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_Material"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category= "Pufferfish"
    bl_options = {"DEFAULT_CLOSED"}

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
     
        obj = context.object
                    
        
        row = layout.row(align = True)
        row.label(text = "change Material Settings here", icon = 'MATERIAL')

    
        box = layout.box()
        
        if obj.get('eye_texture_bool') == 1:
            arrow1 = 'DOWNARROW_HLT'
            OnOff1 = 'ON'
        else:
            arrow1 = 'RIGHTARROW'
            OnOff1 = 'OFF'  
            
        
        #box = layout.box()
        box.prop(context.object, 'eye_texture_bool', text = "Eye Texture: " + OnOff1, icon = arrow1)    
        
        if obj.get('eye_texture_bool') == 1:
            
            box.alignment = 'CENTER'
            box.label(text = "Eye-Textures is activated!", icon = 'TEXTURE_DATA')
            
            box.prop(context.object, 'eye_texture_type', slider=True, text = "Eye Texture Types")
        else:
            box.prop(context.object, 'eye_color', text = "custom eye colour:")
        
        
        
        if obj.get('main_material_bool') == 1:
            arrow2 = 'DOWNARROW_HLT'
        else:
            arrow2 = 'RIGHTARROW'   
            
        box = layout.box()
        box.prop(context.object, 'main_material_bool', text = "Main Material", icon = arrow2)
        
        if obj.get('main_material_bool') == 1:
            
            box.label(text = "main material settings:", icon = 'MODIFIER_OFF')
            
            box.prop(context.object, 'subdivision', slider=True, text = "Subdivisions")

            box.prop(obj, 'sss', slider=True, text = "SubSurfaceScattering")
            
            box.prop(context.object, 'hue', slider=True, text = "Hue")
            
            box.prop(context.object, 'roughness', slider=True, text = "Roughness")
            
            box.prop(context.object, 'saturation', slider=True, text = "Saturation")
        
        
        
class Render(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_parent_id = "OBJECT_PT_Pufferfish_RIG"
    bl_label = "Render Settings"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_RenderSettings"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category= "Pufferfish"
    bl_options = {"DEFAULT_CLOSED"}

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
     
        obj = context.object
        
        scene = context.scene

    
        row = layout.row(align = True)
        row.label(text = "change Render Settings here", icon = 'VIEW_CAMERA')   
        
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("render.render", icon = 'SCENE')




def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(RIG_UI)
    bpy.utils.register_class(MainSettings)
    bpy.utils.register_class(Material)
    bpy.utils.register_class(Render)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(RIG_UI)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MainSettings)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Material)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Render)
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

[image: I'd like to control different node value inputs with these four sliders (or more)]

Comment: You can define an `update` method in properties which will be called everytime their value changes. Use that to update their respective counterpart values in your materials https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#update-example

Comment: First, thank you for your fast reply.

But I have got some problems implenting that.

I added following code:

def update_roughness(self, context):
   obj = context.obj
   roughness = obj.roughness
   bpy.data.materials['Pufferfish'].node_tree.nodes['0'].default_values = float(bpy.data.objects["Pufferfish"].roughness)


But I didnt change anythind in the class drawing the UI. and it didnt work for me.
I am sure I made sth wrong. I tested adding a driver to that (not in python) ... this works. But what would be the solution to make that only via python?

thanks in advance :D

Comment: did you add `update = update_roughness` in your property definition too ?

Comment: `def update_roughness(self, context):
   obj = context.obj
   roughness = obj.roughness
bpy.data.materials['Pufferfish'].node_tree.nodes['PufferfishShader'].inputs[0].default_values = float(bpy.data.objects["Pufferfish"].roughness)`

This is my update def

And this is my property:

`bpy.types.Object.roughness = bpy.props.FloatProperty(
 name = "roughness",
 default = 1,
 min = 0.2,
 max = 5,
 update = update_roughness
 )`

So I have got `update = update_roughness` but is the def update function scripted correctly? Maybe this is the problem. Sorry for bothering you, and thanks